# How to display every row in database but not repeat?

Tags: php, html

I want to display all rows in my database into my html table but it will not repeat the same data, how can I do this? please help me thanks. here is my table.

My table:

[image]

Here is my html and php code:

```
<?php
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM turnoveritems");

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <table id="studentTable" class="display" border="2px">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Reference #</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>ACTION</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>" . $row["reference"] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>
                                <td class='text-center'>" . "<a href='viewturnover.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "'><i class='fa fa-eye fa-2x text-center' title='View full Details'></i></a> " ." </td>
                            </tr>";
                    } echo"</table>"; } else { echo"0 results";};
                    mysqli_close($con);
                    ?>
```

Comment: if the name is already show it will not repeat.

Comment: @TarangP just edited the question. thanks!

Comment: @TarangP thankyou Very much!

Comment: Should your database contain duplicate data in the first place.  It may be worth fixing this if it should all be unique.

Comment: you can mark as answer if it finds helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use SQL Distinct

you can query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table
```

**MORE :** https://www.dofactory.com/sql/select-distinct

Comment: As per @renren Requirement this is perfect answer.i dont think it can be downvoted.

Comment: already done! already mark it